# jquery fullcalendar get duplicate calendar when i'm using jquery replaceWith in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

i implements jquery full calendar in rails, but when i replace div id="calendar", i get duplicate calendar?

i following this tutorial : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

i want select calendar with different value, when i selected drop down value.

this is my code :

```
<%= link_to "new event", filter_path_new_event, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br><br>
<%= label_tag "select_spa_:" %>
<%= select_tag "sleect_spa", "<option>Select Spa</option><option>Park Cities</option><option>Addison</option>".html_safe, onchange: "select_spa()" %>
<br>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
    function select_spa(){
        var place = $("#sleect_spa").val(); 
        var events = "";
        if(place != "Select Spa"){
            events = "/events?place="+place+"&start=2014-05-23&end=2014-09-26";     
        }else{
            events
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          editable: true,
          selectable: true,
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'agendaDay',
          height: 800,
          firstHour: 10,
          minTime: 9,
          maxTime: 22,
          slotMinutes: 15,
          events: events,
          timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
          dragOpacity: "0.5"
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

fix my problem with puts this code before call ('#calendar').fullCalendar() :

```
$(".fc-header").remove();
$(".fc-content").remove();
```